# mongodb store Date in different types

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I use mongodb-java-driver and morphia to save entity into mongodb, entity has three fields of `java.util.Date` type: `createDate, lastUpdateDate and delDate`.

[image]

I set entity `createDate` with `new Date()`, set `lastUpdateDate` and `delDate` with `new Date(specific milliseconds)`, after saving into mongodb,  in Robomongo, it shows `createDate` is `ISODate` type, `lastUpdateDate` and `delDate` are `Date` type, why this happened?  how to keep them in unified `ISODate` type?

[image]

Comment: versions:mongodb 4.0.3, mongodb-java-driver 3.8.2, morphia 1.3.2. I can post code if it's needed.

Comment: I would be curious to see the entity code for sure.  Nothing comes to mind offhand except for maybe ranges supported on the server by the various date types.

Comment: @evanchooly, you are right, date out of the range(year after 2261) will be stored as Date instead of ISODate.

Answer (score 0):

Date out of range is stored as Date, not ISODate.